# Mongoid Return Specific Object from Array in Document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

This seems as though it should be simple but I have been struggling with this for a while with no luck.

Let's assume I have a simple document that looks like the following:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      name: "Minnesota",
    },
    {
      name: "Mississippi",
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

If I run the following query in my Mongo Shell, everything works as I would expect:

```
db.collection.find({}, {data: {$elemMatch: {name: "Michigan"}}})
```

Returns:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e9ba60998d1ff88be83fffe"), "data" : [ { "name" : "Michigan" } ] }
```

However, using `mongoid`, attempting to run a similar query returns every object inside of the data array. Here is one of the may queries I've tried:

```
Model.where({data: {"$elemMatch": {name: "Michigan"}}}).first
```

As I mentioned above, that little query returns everything inside the data array, not the specific object I'm trying to pull out of the document.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm trying to avoid returning the results and post-processing them with Ruby. I'd love to handle this at the DB level.

Thank you.

Comment: Your first example does the `$elemMatch` in the projection, while your second example does it as part of the filter. Does your `Model.where()` have to ability to control projection?

Comment: I didn't want to be too wordy in my question, but ya, I've even tried the following: `db = Mongoid.default_client.database` `collection = db[:collection]` and `collection.find({}, {data: {"$elemMatch": {name: "Michigan"}}})` - no luck. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a very similar question earlier for a different driver.  Apparently the ruby driver behaves differently than the shell.

Try running your find as the equivalent database command:

```
session.command({'find' => 'my_collection', 'filter' => {}, projection => {data: {$elemMatch: {name: "Michigan"}}}})
```

Comment: Awesome. Works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Mongoid syntax for projections is [only](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-queries/#only).